# How to order facets by variable in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

Suppose I have a graph like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl, gear) %>%
  summarise(hp_mean = mean(hp))

  ggplot(df, aes(x = gear, y = hp_mean)) +
  geom_point(size = 2.12, colour = "black") +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(vars(cyl))
```

and would like to arrange the order of facets, according to the hp_mean value for gear=3. E.g. the facet with cyl=8 should be first as hp_mean for gear=3 is 194 which is the highest.
Any ideas?
All help is much appreaciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might not be the tidiest answer out there but you could:

- extract the level of `hp` when `gear == 3` to create a variable to order by (`hp_gear3`)
- use `forcats::fct_reorder()` to reorder by the mean of this value across `gear` (from `group_by()` command)
- use `.desc = TRUE` to put in descending order
- plot using `stat_summary` to do the mean calculation for you

```r
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(gear) %>% 
  mutate(hp_gear3 = ifelse(gear == 3, hp, NA),
         cyl = fct_reorder(factor(cyl),
                           hp_gear3, 
                           mean, 
                           na.rm = TRUE,
                           .desc = TRUE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(gear, hp)) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean) +
  facet_wrap(~cyl)
```

[image]